# Is it possible to make ASP.NET url like Angular i.e. localhost:5000/#/etc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

Is it possible to make ASP.NET URLs like Angular URLs, i.e. localhost:5000/#/etc?

I have found many similar questions about URL formats between ASP.NET and Angular, and interoperability - however, I simply wish to know if it is possible to have an ASP.NET application with URLs in that style.

Comment: its possible, we can give http://localhost:5000/MyProject.  In iis we can set default page and virtual path

Comment: I know very little about virtual path, and I think that's what I'm missing. I'll investigate that further. Thanks!